# how to resolve the issue groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am getting an error in jenkins pipeline script. The error says that groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper.getExecutor() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

I am trying to integrate jenkins and grafana

```
   stage('Grafana Results') {

 // grafana url for aggregate dashboard - replace time stamp with %s
   def perfResult = "<grafana url>?orgId=39&from=%s&to=%s"
 // get build start and end time
  def start = currentBuild.getStartTimeInMillis();
  def end = start + currentBuild.getExecutor().getElapsedTime();
// replace time
  perfResult = String.format(perfResult, start, end);


 //build the string to be added as description.
  def link = "<a href='%s'>%s</a><br/>";
 def sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append(String.format(link, perfResult, "Grafana Performance Result"));

 // set build description
   currentBuild.setDescription(sb.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

first - you have to read error. there is an answer in it:

> No signature of method:
>
> `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper.getExecutor()`
>
> is applicable for argument types: () values: []

search the documentation for the class `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper`:

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html

and in this class there is no method `getExecutor()`.

however there is a `getRawBuild()` method that returns https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html

so, probably this will work for you:

```
currentBuild.getRawBuild().getExecutor().getElapsedTime()
```